# Retrieve nested data from firebase database Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

[image]

I have to retrieve this data from Firebase Database and show it in UITableView. I created an Exercise class to store the object and after that, I have to store these Exercise objects in exercisesArray of type Exercise. I am able to retrieve values but not able to store in Exercise object. how can i do this? please help.

Exercise Class -

```
class Exercise: NSObject {


        var name: String?
        var bodyPart: String?
        var sets: String?
        var exerciseDescription: String?
        var image: String?

    init(name: String?, bodyPart: String?, sets: String?, exerciseDescription: String?, image: String? ) {
        self.name = name
        self.bodyPart = bodyPart
        self.sets = sets
        self.exerciseDescription = exerciseDescription
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Retrieve Method

```
class ExerciseList{

    func getExerciseDataFromDatabase(bodyPart: String){
            //var exercises: NSDictionary = [:]
            dbRef?.child("exercises/bodyParts").child(bodyPart).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let values = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                   print(values)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```